# Editing a command-line argument to create a new variable

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a bash script called `test.sh` that uses command-line argument:

```
lynx -dump $1 > $name".txt"
```

But I need name to be created from the argument by specific keywords in the argument.

An example is:

```
http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2412941,00.asp
http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2412919,00.asp
```

Both are two separate articles but are the difference can only be seen in those 12 characters. How do I create a variable from a url for those 12 characters? So that when I run test.sh in Terminal:

```
./test.sh http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2412941,00.asp
```

there is a text file saved as `0,2817,2412941,00`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in awk like this:

```
$ name=$(echo $1 | awk -F[/.] '{print $(NF-1)}')
$ echo $name
0,2817,2412941,00
```

By using `/` and `.` as delimiters, the stuff you want will be present in the last but one field which can be accessed using `NF-1`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `basename` command:

```
basename http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2412919,00.asp ".asp"
```

which will give you:

```
0,2817,2412919,00
```

Comment: This works for one link but I'm dealing with over 100 links and the job would become tedious. But thank you nevertheless!

Comment: You could of course also use another line to get the extension first, and then use it in this line. But then you're indeed better of with Gurus solution.